# Trying to get node.js to work with HID device

Tags: node.js, hid

I'm working on a node.js project to communicate with a Magtek eDynamo card reader using [node-hid](https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid)  I'm able to get connected and wait for data to be sent, but when I try and send feature report requests the code fails every time.

I'm using the [programming manual here](https://www.magtek.com/Content/DocumentationFiles/D998200115.pdf) to get information needed to send the report requests.  I've tried the following with zero success.

```
var HID = require('node-hid');
var os = require('os');

var device_array = HID.devices('0x0801', '0x0019');
console.log(device_array);

if (device_array.length > 1){
  console.log('More than one magstripe reader is plugged in!');
  process.exit(1);
} else if (device_array.length == 0){
  console.log('No magstripe reader is plugged in!');
  process.exit(1);
}

var device = device_array[0];
var magstripe = new HID.HID(device.path);

magstripe.sendFeatureReport([0x20,0x09,0x00,0x00]); // Report request
```

For the report request I have tried the following

0x00 (all reports ran below with and without the zero bit at beginning for win32 per documentation)

0x20, 0x09, 0x00 (no last zero bit)

0x20, 0x09, 0x00 0x00 (data bit zero per documentation)

0x09, 0x00

0x09, 0x00, 0x00

Any help would be much appreciated as Magtek support is not very helpful and I'm stumped.

error I receive

```
Error: could not send feature report to device
at Object.<anonymous> (L:\code\nodejs\node-hid\index.js:45:22)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

NOTE: index.js 45:22 is this code

```
var resp = magstripe.sendFeatureReport(messageA);
```

Comment: When you say "fails every time", what is your failure symptom? I scanned the doco and it would seem that even if the command packet has no data, you would still have to send a fixed amount of data in your sendFeatureReport. Then you would have to call getFeatureReport to obtain the response - which may indicate further errors - which for command 0x09 is either 0x00="Success" or 0x02="Bad parameter. The Request Data is not the correct length". You would need to capture the HID Report Descriptor when you plug the device in to determine the feature report (0x20) length required.

Comment: Updated post with error, apologies

Comment: An earlier version (ca 2012) of a Magtek Sureswipe reader had a documented 0x20 feature report length of 24 bytes. I'd try that first. Failing that you'll either have to capture the HID Report Descriptor, or experiment by padding your sendFeatureReport array with 0x00 bytes i.e. 0x20 0x09 0x00 followed by up to 58 null bytes until it works (according to Section 2.1.2 of the programmer's reference),

Comment: Thanks aja, will play around with that some more.  Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into is that you are sending a partial array.
For this to work you should always initialize your array to the full page-size.

I have it working with Dynamag and DanaPro devices, and the easiest way I've found is to initialize a buffer (which is zero-filled) and then Array.from( my_buffer )... see example below.

```
let bytes = Buffer.alloc(64);
/* set data in the buffer */
bytes[0] = 0x20;
bytes[1] = 0x09;
// now send it
magstripe.sendFeatureReport(Array.from(data));
```

Alternatively you can add something like the following on an Array instead of buffers:

```
Array.prototype.zeroFill = function (len) {
    for (var i = this.length; i < len; i++) {
        this[i] = 0;
    }
    return this;
};
```

then using your example (specifying your devices page size):

```
magstripe.sendFeatureReport( [0x20,0x09,0x00,0x00].zeroFill(64) );
```

Comment: I will test this out when I get some time.  I moved to another option with their offerings which is working well so far.  Thank you for the suggestion.